# Conditional expressions in shell: What are the differences between [ vs [[

Tags: bash, shell, ksh, test, coreutils

I just wondered about some people writing

```
if [[ <expr> ]]; then ...
```

in answers here when I out of habit would use

```
if [ <expr> ]; then ...
```

Doing a [quick research](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest) reveals that `[[ ]]` seems to be a shell builtin introduced once by the Korn shell and also provided by [Bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (and others perhaps), while `[ ]` is just a shortcut for the external command `test` and thus equal to

```
if test <expr>; then ...
```

Now,

1. Are there differences between the individual implementations? (Leaving aside *busybox* as a stripped-down shell/test implementation.)
   Edit: Best answers by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184293/157411 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56666/157411.
2. Are there cases where one should or must be preferred over the other? (Except when one of them isn't available, e. g. in a very restricted environment.)
   Edit: Best answer by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56666/157411; in short if you would like to avoid quoting issues and use the common operators instead of switches use `[[ ]]`.
3. Which one to use for maximum compatibility? (And I hope this is unambiguously answerable...)
   Edit: Best answer by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56674/157411; in short if you want to be compatible use `test` or `[ ]`.

Edit: Related questions and answers:

- [Why is `[` a shell builtin and `[[` a shell keyword?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/why-is-a-shell-builtin-and-a-shell-keyword)
- [What is the difference between [[ $a == z* ]] and [ $a == z* ]?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56655/what-is-the-difference-between-a-z-and-a-z/56674)
- [using single or double bracket - bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/using-single-or-double-bracket-bash)

Comment: Excellent; unfortunately searching for "[ [[" didn't reveal that.

Comment: @cuonglm Now as my question hasn't much use except being a link collection to the answers, would you prefer to have me delete it?

Comment: I can't, only mark it as duplicated.