# call `time` with format option

Tags: linux, time

I want to measure execution time of commands and get (to me) strange behavior of the `time` command.

I call `time` like it is mentioned in the examples of the manpages with the `-f` or `--format` option and get a `command not found` error. Seems like it thinks `-f` is the command to measure the execution time of...

```
user@laptop:~$ time -f '%e' sleep 1
-f: Befehl nicht gefunden.
```

Then I call the same line again, just that I specify the path to `time`. Result changes, works as intended (wtf?):

```
user@laptop:~$ /usr/bin/time -f '%e' sleep 1
1.00
```

Now I'm confused... even `which` can't help me:

```
user@pc:~$ which time
/usr/bin/time
```

And... if I don't use options it works fine, even without full path:

```
user@laptop:~$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.002s
```

How do I use this command correctly if I want to specify options?
Using the full path seems to work, but looks more like an unreliable side effect of something buggy (or something I don't understand)?

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty)

Comment: also good: http://askubuntu.com/questions/434289/why-time-command-doesnt-work-with-any-option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Bash` has a built in command called `time`. So if you just type `time` it will use the shell built-in which has no options like `-f`. But `man time` (which talks about `-f`) will give the manpage of the `/usr/bin/time` program. So if you want to use options described in the manpage you should ensure you call the program, not the shell built-in. One way achieving this is using the full path.

(IMHO, this is really ugly in bash)

For more info, see the links below the question.

Comment: Actually time isn't a shell builtin it's a reserved word.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/why-is-a-shell-builtin-and-a-shell-keyword `Similar to a builtin, a keyword is hard-coded into Bash, but unlike a builtin, a keyword is not in itself a command, but a subunit of a command construct.` So are you saying time is a `subunit of a command construct` ?

Comment: It is in POSIX, The reason: time "needs" to be transparent to pipes and redirections.  The "needs": for practical common uses and historical reasons.  EDIT: POSIX uses "times", but the reason is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would add a way to show the info for Boris's answer.

As was just puzzled by time again.

In bash `type` is your friend. I should really remember to use it more. Old `csh` habits die hard.

```
which -a time  
/usr/bin/time

type time 
time is a shell keyword

type times  
times is a shell builtin

type nslookup  
nslookup is /usr/bin/nslookup
```