# Getting an error in the if condition

Tags: bash, shell-script, syntax

I am just checking whether the password contains a small and capital case letter, I am getting an error at line 19.

`myscript.sh`:

```
#!bin/sh

read password
conditionarr=(0 0)

if [[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]]
then
   condtionarr[1]=1
fi


if [[ $password =~ [a-z] ]]
then
   conditionarr[0]=1
fi


if [ ${conditionarr[0]} == 1 || ${conditionarr[1]} == 1 ]
then
    printf "%s" "Yes\n "
else
    printf "%s" "No\n"
fi
```

The error:

```
./myscript.sh: line 19: [: missing `]'

./myscript.sh: line 19: 0: command not found
```

What is wrong with this code? Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah  , it's a mistake, thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

- The `#!`-line should read `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever the full absolute path is to the `bash` interpreter or your system).  Note that you are using shell code that requires the use of `bash`, so pointing the `#!`-line to the `sh` interpreter would not be correct as that shell may not understand things like the non-standard `[[ ... ]]`, or the use of arrays.
- Passwords should probably be read using `IFS= read -s -r` in `bash` to avoid echoing the input to the terminal, and to allow the use of `\` without issues, and to allow flanking spaces etc.
- Multiple tests are better written `[ ... ] || [ ... ]`.  This is what causes your actual error message.  The `[` utility does not know about `||`.

Suggestion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -p 'Enter password: ' -sr password
check=(0 0)

[[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]] && check[0]=1
[[ $password =~ [a-z] ]] && check[1]=1

if [ "${check[0]}" = 1 ] || [ "${check[1]}" = 1 ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Or, getting rid of the need for the array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -p 'Enter password: ' -sr password

if [[ $password =~ [A-Z] ]] ||
   [[ $password =~ [a-z] ]]
then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Note that testing the `$password` string for matches of `[A-Z]` *or* for matches of `[a-z]` can be done in one test with `[A-Za-z]`.

In the `sh` shell, you could write your script like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Enter password: ' >&2

state=$(stty -g)    # save stty state
stty -echo          # turn off local echo
IFS= read -r password
stty "$state"       # reset stty state to original

case $password in
        *[A-Za-z]*)
                echo yes
                ;;
        *)
                echo no
esac
```

Note that I've combined the tests for upper and lower case characters into a single test, and that the patterns used by `case` are shell globbing patterns, not regular expressions.

If you need to check for upper *and* lower case letters, you still need the two separate tests:

```bash
case $password in (*[A-Z]*) check1=true;; (*) check1=false; esac
case $password in (*[a-z]*) check2=true;; (*) check2=false; esac

if "$check1" && "$check2"; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Comment: What is read -s -r mean?

Comment: @bigstreet See `help read` in an interactive `bash` session, but `-s` turns off local echo so that the password is not displayed while you type it, and `-r` turns off special processing of some characters when preceded by ``\`` in the input (this allows ``\`` to be used in passwords).

Answer (score 1):

Note how you switched from `[[` to `[` for that last condition:

> ```
> if [[ $password =~ [a-z] ]]
>
> if [ ${conditionarr[0]} == 1 || ${conditionarr[1]} == 1 ]
> ```

There's a big difference between the two, namely that `[[` is a special shell construct, and has its own syntax, while `[` is just a regular command.

See:

- [Why is `[` a shell builtin and `[[` a shell keyword?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183745/170373)
- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373)

In `[ ${conditionarr[0]} == 1 || ...`, the `||` terminates the command, so what runs is just `[ whatever == 1`. But `[` expects to see a `]` as a final argument, so that the command looks nicer. There isn't one now, so it complains. (Also with `[`, you should quote the variable expansions for [all the usual reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting), and use `=` instead of `==`, as the latter isn't standard.)

You could use either of

```
if [    "${conditionarr[0]}" = 1 ] || [    "${conditionarr[1]}" = 1 ]
# or
if test "${conditionarr[0]}" = 1   || test "${conditionarr[1]}" = 1
```

but it'd be easier to just switch to `[[` instead, since it does support `||` within it and is actually safer with missing quoting (on the left-hand side of `==` anyway):

```
if [[ ${conditionarr[0]} == 1 || ${conditionarr[1]} == 1 ]]
```