# Two attempts of an if with an "and" are failing: if [ ... ] -a [ ... ] , if [[ ... && ... ]] Why?

Tags: bash

In a bash script, I'm willing to check if a parameter has a boolean value ("true" or "false").
I'm attempting this in two scripts in two different ways, both failing.
I've checked many Stack Exchange hints, and I believe doing what I should, but it isn't the case.

```bash
if [ "$2" != "true" ] -a [ "$2" != "false" ]; then
  echo "Indiquez si Geoserver est en installation initiale (false) ou update (true)" >&2;
  exit 1;
fi
```

fails with the message `Geoserver.sh: 12: [: true: unexpected operator`

```bash
if [[ "$3" != "true" && "$3" != "false" ]]; then
  echo "Indiquez si Kafka est en installation initiale (false) ou update (true)" >&2;
  exit 1;
fi
```

fails with `Kafka.sh: 18: [[: not found`

Comment: Try something like: `if [ "$2"z != "true" ] -a [ "$2" != "false"z ]; then`. ANd usually in `if` are user `&&` and `||` for AND and OR. And the reason for the error for me is `$2` is empty

Comment: Also mention how you run your script. It seems as if you are running it with `sh`, not with `bash`.

Comment: You're both right! My script was called by a `sh` instead of a `bash`.

Comment: I always thought `[ "a" != "a" -a "b" != "b" ]` is the way to combine tests with `-a` based on `man [`.  The alternate to `[ EXPR ]`, `test EXPR` can also be used as well, you can check from the command line: `test "a" = "a" -a "b" = "b"; echo $?`

Comment: @chexum Both `-a` and `-o` are marked obsolete in the POSIX standard (see the "APPLICATION USAGE" section [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)). It's too difficult to write unambiguous code with them.

Comment: @Kusalananda ouch, thanks - this only shows my age, but obsoleting these sounds to me so unacceptable as obsoleting fgrep/egrep :)

Comment: @chexum Sometimes it's just better to accept change :-) And the preferred new way of doing this looks easier to read, IMHO. As for `fgrep` and `egrep`, adding standard options to `grep` did sound better than having a proliferation of utilities that do essentially the same thing, but I agree that muscle memory is difficult to re-train.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both errors suggest you are not using `bash` at all, but some lesser featured shell, such as `dash` for example.

Furthermore, in your first example, you have incorrectly implemented an "and" clause.

This is what I think you were going for, and should work if you actually were to use `bash`:

```
if [ "$2" != "true" -a "$2" != "false" ]; then
```

Although the preferred method tends to be this more portable option:

```
if [ "$2" != "true" ] && [ "$2" != "false" ]; then
```

The error for the second example again suggests you are not using a shell that supports `[[ ]]` notation, if you change to the above `[ ] && [ ]` style notation you may have more success.

Comment: The error messages indeed match what Dash would print

Comment: `-a` is broken by design and deprecated and should NOT be used. It doesn't work reliably, in bash included (especially in bash). `bash -c '[ "$2" != "true" -a "$2" != "false" ]' bash x '!'` for instance fails with `bash: line 1: [: too many arguments`

Answer (score 12):

The standard way would be

```
[ "$3" != "true" ] && [ "$3" != "false" ]
```

That is to run two `[` commands each performing a single test and chained with the shell's `&&` operator.

`[[...]]` is special non-standard shell syntax from ksh, supported by many feature-rich shells, and it does (usually) support `&&` inside the brackets. It should be available in `bash` as long as `bash` was not built with `--disable-cond-command`, but the wording of your error message suggests you're rather using the `dash` shell. With a `bash` built with `--disable-cond-command`, the errors would rather be: `Geoserver.sh: 12: [: too many arguments` and `Kafka.sh: 18: [[: command not found` respectively.

`-a` would be supported within `[` for backward compatibility, as in `[ "$2" != "true" -a "$2" != "false" ]`, but is deprecated and broken by design and (like its `-o` counterpart for *or*) should not be used.

It's complicated, see e.g.

- [Why is `[` a shell builtin and `[[` a shell keyword?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183745/why-is-a-shell-builtin-and-a-shell-keyword) and
- [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs) and
- [Why does parameter expansion with spaces without quotes work inside double brackets "[[" but not inside single brackets "["?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/why-does-parameter-expansion-with-spaces-without-quotes-work-inside-double-brack)